# javascript event.preventdefault() not working on jquery.click with Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a Rails form. But I dont want to submit the form through Rails. I want to submit it through Ajax.

In view file

```
          <li><%= submit_tag 'Save', id: 'submit', :class => 'button' %></li>
```

In js file

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
    alert("hi");
    event.preventDefault();

    health_marks_array = form_hash_and_submit();
    if (0 < health_marks_array.length) {
        call_form_submit(health_marks_array);
    }
    else{
        location.href = '/thinking_health_card/health_marks/new?form_name=' + form_name + '&student_id=' + student_id + '&health_exam_id=' + health_exam_id
    }
    return false

});
```

Also tried

```
$(".submit").click(function(event) {
    alert("hi");
    event.preventDefault();

    health_marks_array = form_hash_and_submit();
    if (0 < health_marks_array.length) {
        call_form_submit(health_marks_array);
    }
    else{
        location.href = '/thinking_health_card/health_marks/new?form_name=' + form_name + '&student_id=' + student_id + '&health_exam_id=' + health_exam_id
    }
    return false

});
```

Why it is not working?

Comment: what is not working ?

Comment: The element has an ID of `submit` which is a bad idea, and a class of `button`

Comment: @adeneo i bet that's his issue - class selector instead of id

Comment: And it's not the button you want to target, but the forms `submit` event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change, from

```
$(".submit").click(function() {});
```

To

```
$("#submit").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   ....
});
```

Element has id `#submit`, not class `.submit`